# How do I add a JLabel to an already made JFrame if it has no name because the name was created in another class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

For example I can't make a button add a label to a specific `JFrame` that has no name because I can only do `this.add` but this doesn't work because it's not in the `JFrame` constructor.

This is my `JFrame` that I'm trying to add the label to.

```java
GameWindow() {
    label.setText("Money: "+ userMoney);
    BButton = myButton("Balooga: 20$", 50, 50, 125, 50);
    BButton.addActionListener(this);
    CButton = myButton("Canca", 225, 50, 125, 50);
    CButton.addActionListener(this);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(102,102,255));
    this.setTitle("Gambling");
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(1920,1080);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.add(BButton);
    this.add(CButton);
    this.add(label);
    this.add(caseQuestion);
}
```

---

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==BButton) {
        userMoney = userMoney - 20;
        label.setText("Money: "+ userMoney);
        JLabel itemLabel = BaloogaCase.bCase();//THIS IS THE LABEL I'M TRYING TO ADD VIA BUTTON TOUCH
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==CButton) {
        label.setText("Money: "+ userMoney);
    }
```

I'm assuming the problem is because the `JFrame` is being summoned from another class so I can't put a name to it but I'm almost 100% positive there is a way to create a new name for the `JFrame` or import it to another class somehow.

For example I have my initial `JFrame` that has general info and a button to `dispose()` of that `JFrame` and open a new `JFrame` that is located in a different class, so the `JFrame` opens but I can only add labels directly to the `JFrame` not after the `JFrame` is made because the `JFrame` name isn't universal I guess.

Comment: [mcve] - everything else is guess work

Comment: So based on `CButton.addActionListener(this);` and `this.add(BButton);`, the `ActionListener is been implemented within the contents of the class extending from `JFrame`, so `JLabel itemLabel = BaloogaCase.bCase();` and `this.add(itemLabel)` should be a viable solution. Of course, you will need `revalidate` and `repaint` the parent container after modifying like this - but this is all guess work